# How to export listbox items into XML file

Tags: c#, xml, listbox, export-to-xml

I'm trying to export the **list box** items into **xml file** , I'm able to export single value objects such as text box, radio button, check boxes...

```
<Setting Name="txt_ImageQuality">20</Setting>
<Setting Name="txt_ImageType">JPG</Setting>
<Setting Name="rdio_checkedStatus">True</Setting>
```

but I want to export the following listbox items into XML.

[image]

is there any ways around in c#, thanks for your time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could you please try the below code snippet and please vote the answer if its usefult

```
XElement element = new XElement("Items");
foreach (var item in listBox1.Items)
{
  element.Add(new XElement("Name", item));
}
XDocument document = new XDocument();
document.Add(element);
document.Save("items.xml",SaveOptions.DisableFormatting); //create items.xml file in bin folder
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the above

```
var xml = new XElement("Items",
from s in strings 
let parts = s.Split('=')
select new XElement("Item", 
    new XAttribute("Key", parts[0]), 
    parts[1]
)
```

);

Comment: Thanks for your response,I do not have any knowledge on Linq & when I tried your code, I get the following response: The Index was outside the bounds of the array.